# How do I update the expansion tooltip size after calling NSTextField setStringValue:?

Tags: macos, tooltip, nstextfield, appkit

When a view contains an `NSTextField` with the expansion tooltip enabled and the text doesn't fit, then the user hovers the cursor over the field, OS X shows an expansion tooltip. If you then call `setStringValue:` to change the text content of the `NSTextField`, the expansion tooltip's size is not updated. For instance, if the original text was 100 characters long but the new text is only 50 characters long, hovering over the new text will show an expansion tooltip large enough for 100 characters containing the new text. This is true even if the new string fits entirely in the `NSTextField`, which normally would prevent an expansion tooltip appearing.

The opposite also occurs: If the original string fits within the `NSTextField`, no expansion tooltip appears. If the new string does not fit within the `NSTextField`, no expansion tooltip appears even though it should.

Internally, the `NSTextField`'s `NSTextFieldCell` implements the `NSCell` method `expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:`. Something (I'm not sure what) calls this once, and seems to cache the result. Setting a new string using `setStringValue:` does not cause this function to be called again.

Calling `setNeedsDisplay` on the NSTextField after calling `setStringValue:` does not fix this.

So how do I get AppKit to resize the expansion tooltip?

Comment: I've answered my own question, but I won't accept my answer for now, in case someone comes up with a less-hacky way to address this problem.

Comment: I find it sadly amusing that most Cocoa questions are answered in a hackish way by the author of the question...

Comment: I just realized I left the comment above 3 years ago. Thanks again for posting this.

Answer (score 3):

After a great deal of experimentation, I found two methods to fix this.

The very difficult way is to delete and recreate the entire `NSTextField` each time the text changes. This is laborious because `NSTextField` doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, so you have to use an `NSArchiver` and an `NSUnarchiver` to duplicate the original `NSTextField`, and even then some attributes are not copied, such as constraints.

The easy way is to hide and un-hide the `NSTextField`.

```
NSTextField *textField;
{...}
[textField setStringValue:newText];
[textField setHidden:YES];
[textField setHidden:NO];
```

This makes AppKit call `expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:` on the `NSTextField`'s `NSTextFieldCell`, which properly updates the expansion tooltip's presence and size.

Answer (score 0):

`[textField resetCursorRects]` seems to cause `expansionFrameWithFrame:inView:` to be called on the `NSTextFieldCell` as well. Tested only in macOS 10.14.