# Expand tooltip on hover in NSCollectionView not working after ReloadData or tab change

Tags: xcode, nscollectionview

I have an NSCollectionView inside a Tab which contains subviews with NSTextField that have expanding tooltips.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Strangely, after a new search (ReloadData) or going to a tab and coming back, the tooltips no longer expand. They come back only if I resize the window or scroll the CollectionView*. Clicking in the view does not help. What can I do to automatically have the tooltips work?

*This triggers the CollectionView and the CollectionViewItems to UpdateTrackingAreas. I tried to force this on ReloadData even delayed 1000 ms, but this did not make the tooltips able to expand.

Thoughts:

- Something related to UpdateTrackingAreas but not exactly?
- Maybe a first responder issue?
- It also doesn't work if the window is not the active window (which is ok)
- Concerned that it might be related to [How do I update the expansion tooltip size after calling NSTextField setStringValue:?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920982/how-do-i-update-the-expansion-tooltip-size-after-calling-nstextfield-setstringva)

Comment: How did you implement the tooltip?

Comment: I just allowed the expansion tooltip and resized my view to be smaller. Turns out that this - How do I update the expansion tooltip size after calling NSTextField setStringValue:? - fixes the issue with a hack of hiding and unhiding the textfield. strange hack!

Comment: Instead of hiding and unhiding, try `resetCursorRects` (which is triggered by unhiding).

Comment: I just tried it, but resetCursorRects does not work. Back to hide and unhide.